# Design of Restful API with HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: php, api, rest, session, http-authentication

*Note: I know there are LOTS of other StackOverflow questions dealing with this topic. I've read through many of them, as well as many other websites. I still have the following questions.*

So, I'm building a REST API for a new product. At this time the API is entirely for private consumption by our websites and phone apps. However, I'm thinking it might be smart to design the API so that it can be made public in the future.

### Authentication

While I've looked at OAuth, I think HTTP Basic Authentication over SSL is plenty secure enough for our API. From what I understand HTTP Basic Authentication over SSL is a completely viable way of authenticating a REST API. It's also quite simple, which is appealing for me since I'm new to API development.

### Authorization

If a user logs in to the API using their username and password, they will only be given access to certain parts of the API. Meaning they'll have access to their own content, but not the content of other users. Further, they may be limited to what they can all do.

In addition to the user accounts, I plan to also have other other (non user) accounts for more global administrative tasks. These accounts could potentially have full access to the API.

Is this a good design? OR, is it bad to authenticate a user in this way? Should I only be authenticating my clients (ie. apps) this way?

### Sessions

My big question is, when logging a user into our web app, how do I manage their sessions? REST stipulates sending the username and password with each request. Further, REST API's are stateless, so I cannot manage sessions there. However, I need to track that they've logged into the web app somehow. They clearly can't possibly login manually for each request.

One approach is, after a user logs in, we save their login credentials (email & password) to the PHP session. Then, each subsequent request to the API could use those credentials. However, saving usernames and passwords in a PHP session just feels wrong and very unsafe. But if not done this way, how are people managing sessions when interacting with a REST API?

The phone apps are easier, as you can save the user's login credentials into a keychain.

Can anyone help with my design questions?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old and maybe you already finished your work, but I'd like to give you some tips. Maybe these could help you or anybody in the future. :)

**Authentication**

HTTP Basic Auth over SSL is quite simple, that's true, but not so secure than you think. You only have to install 1 "fake" SSL cert on the client and with a man in the middle attack you can sniff the traffic.

How to install a fake certificate? It's not so hard in a browser lot of users just click on the ok when they see the huge red warning screen. On a mobile for example: http://cryptopath.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/iphone-certificate-flaws/

With this solution you only have to intercept the traffic once and you'll have the user's password!

My tip: Generate a temporary password at login and use this in every other requests. So the attacker have to intercept the login process for the password and if you store this pass locally on the phone for example it's much harder. (And of course you can add expiration to it etc...)

**Authorization**

I don't really understand what would you do. User access management is a good thing, but it depends on the given project.

**Session**

Not only the REST APIs, teh whole HTTP world is stateless. If you use a PHP session it stores a session id in a cookie on the client side and the browser sends this cookie value every time to the server.

The users don't have to login every time. They log in once and get a token/temporary password etc... and (or if you don't use these stuff) they send you a basic auth header at every requests.
This way you can easily track who sent you the request, because you already now who's that user and you can store and link some data to it on the server.

There are many ways to deal with users. Basic auth is one of them. And check this: [OAuth's tokens and sessions in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672530/oauths-tokens-and-sessions-in-rest)
"OAuth tokens are explicitly a session identifier, ..."

You don't have to store the user's password and email, you just have to check the headers/cookies/etc... from the client in every requests.

> The phone apps are easier, as you can save the user's login
>   credentials into a keychain.

They can, but saving the user's real password on a phone is a very bad practice. Save a time limited token is a bit better. :)

In every other languages you can store values if you want. For example if you want to use a Python client for your API: It authenticates and stores a token or something what it needs in a variable and at every other requests it uses this stored data.

One more sidenote:

> However, saving usernames and passwords in a PHP session just feels
>   wrong and very unsafe.

True that's unsafe, but the (real) PHP sessions are stored on the server side and as I said it stores only a single session id on the client side. Anybody who can get this session id, could impersonate the given user. (There are countermeasures for example IP check, etc...)